# Dump the kafka (kafka-python) to a txt file

Tags: python, apache-kafka, kafka-python

I need to dump the output of the kafka consumer into an excel file periodically. I use the following code:

```
from kafka import KafkaConsumer
from kafka import KafkaProducer
import json,time
from xlutils.copy import copy    
from xlrd import open_workbook
import pandas

consumer = KafkaConsumer(bootstrap_servers='localhost:9092')
KafkaConsumer()
consumer.subscribe("test")

rowx=0
colx=0

for msg in consumer:
        book_ro = open_workbook("twitter.xls")
        book = copy(book_ro)  # creates a writeable copy
        sheet1 = book.get_sheet(0)  # get a first sheet
        sheet1.write(rowx,colx, msg[6])
        book.save("twitter.xls")
```

Now, my issue is that the code is not efficient. for each message I need to open, write, and then save the excel file. Is there any approach to open the excel once, write, and then close it (for a batch of messages and not in the for loop)? tnx

Comment: Why close the file at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, open,write,save and close with each message is inefficient, you could do it in a batch. But still need do it in consuming loop.

```
msg_buffer = []
buffer_size = 100
for msg in consumer:
        msg_buffer.append(msg[6])
        if len(msg_buffer) >= buffer_size:
            book_ro = open_workbook("twitter.xls")
            book = copy(book_ro)  # creates a writeable copy
            for _msg in msg_buffer:
                sheet1 = book.get_sheet(0)  # get a first sheet
                sheet1.write(rowx,colx, _msg)
            book.save("twitter.xls")
            msg_buffer = []
```

You could think that will be 100 times faster than nobatch.

**UPDATE for comment:**

Yes, Usually we will stay in this loop forever, it internally uses poll to fetch the new message, send heartbeat and commit offset. And if your aim is consuming message from this topic and save message, it should be a long running loop.

This is kafka-python design, you should use like this to consume message or use the consumer.poll().

As for why you could use `for msg in consumer:`, Because the consumer is an iterator object, its class implements the `__iter__` and `__next__`, it underlying uses a fetcher to fetch records. more implementation details you could refer https://github.com/dpkp/kafka-python/blob/master/kafka/consumer/group.py

Comment: Thanks for the note. I am wondering if we stay in the "for msg in consume loop" forever? In this case, your code is OK. or is there any callback function (when the client really receives a message, it calls a function to do sth)? What is the type of consumer object? is it a list or what?

Comment: answer udpated.